# Verilog confusion about reg and & operator

Tags: verilog, operator-keyword

First time using verilog I saw an example, which is quite confusing.

```
reg wrsigbuf, wrsigrise;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
  wrsigbuf <= wrsig;
  wrsigrise <= (~wrsigbuf) & wrsig;
end
```

My questions are:

1. does `wrsigrise` ever get high in this case.
2. what is the use of the `&` operator, isn't both `~wrsigbuf` and wrsig both high to put `wrsigrise` as high? `~wrsigbuf` will never be high as long as `wrsigbuf` is high, right?

Comment: [Good luck](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/veritut.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I might just answer this myself

'wrsigrise' will become 1 as 'wrsig' become from 0 to 1, while 'wrsigbuf' still in its previous period being assigned by 'wrsig' as 0

Comment: your correct. It is a rising edge detector. used to create a pulse 1 clk period wide when the level changes from 0 to 1.